# Possible Mocking Framework for Unit Testing a SingleCore PureMVC project

Tags: unit-testing, flexunit, puremvc

I have an old and large PureMVC Singlecore project that I am joining.
I'm trying to help my team create unit tests for what we have and to teach them how to write unit tests as we go forward.

I'm encountering a bunch of mocking problems with vague references to display objects, Notifications, and the fact that most of the functions which have testable code are private functions.

Searching the internet for mock utilities or tools for unit testing puremvc results mainly in projects that appear to be no longer supported (from 2008 or 2010)

I'm asking which tools exist to solve this sort of problem today, from people who are active in the community.

Thanks.

If this is not the right place to ask this question, please point me to a place where this question can get answered.